# Docker-Machine and Swarm behind proxy

Tags: proxy, docker, docker-machine, docker-swarm

I'm traing to set up docker swarm over my virtual cluster. First, I try to install the swarm-master on the localhost with docker-machine.

The problem is that the machine need to use a proxy to access the discovery token.

First I ask a token with swarm create. To do that, I created this file :

```
$cat /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http_proxy.conf 
[Service]
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://**.**.**.**:3128/"    "HTTPS_PROXY=http://**.**.**.**:3128/" "NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1,192.168.2.100,192.168.2.101,192.168.2.102,192.168.2.103,192.168.2.104,192.168.2.105,192.168.2.106,192.168.2.107,192.168.2.108,192.168.2.194,192.168.2.110"
```

I restarted the daemon and I can pull the swarm image :

```
$docker run -e "http_proxy=http://**.**.**.**:3128/" -e "https_proxy=http://**.**.**.**:3128/" swarm create
b54d8665e72939d2c611d8f9e99521b4
```

After I want to create the swarm master :

```
$docker-machine create -d generic --generic-ip-address localhost \
--engine-env HTTP_PROXY=http://192.168.254.10:3128/ \
--engine-env HTTPS_PROXY=http://192.168.254.10:3128/ \
--engine-env NO_PROXY=localhost,192.168.2.102,192.168.2.100 \
--swarm --swarm-master --swarm-discovery \
token://b54d8665e72939d2c611d8f9e99521b4 swarm-master
```

Result :

```
Running pre-create checks...
Creating machine...
Waiting for machine to be running, this may take a few minutes...
Machine is running, waiting for SSH to be available...
Detecting operating system of created instance...
Provisioning created instance...
Copying certs to the local machine directory...
Copying certs to the remote machine...
Setting Docker configuration on the remote daemon...
Configuring swarm...
To see how to connect Docker to this machine, run: docker-machine env swarm-master
```

And I have errors in the logs of the join and manage container (I think the error come because the containers don't take care of the proxy) :

```
$docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                              NAMES
6fbf967cdb60        swarm:latest        "/swarm join --advert"   53 seconds ago      Up 52 seconds       2375/tcp                           swarm-agent
8b176116989e        swarm:latest        "/swarm manage --tlsv"   54 seconds ago      Up 53 seconds       2375/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3376->3376/tcp   swarm-agent-master

$docker logs 6fbf967cdb60
time="2015-11-17T19:37:21Z" level=info msg="Registering on the discovery service every 20s..." addr="localhost:2376" discovery="token://b54d8665e72939d2c611d8f9e99521b4" 
time="2015-11-17T19:37:41Z" level=error msg="Post https://discovery.hub.docker.com/v1/clusters/b54d8665e72939d2c611d8f9e99521b4?ttl=60: dial tcp: lookup discovery.hub.docker.com on 8.8.4.4:53: read udp 172.17.0.3:46576->8.8.4.4:53: i/o timeout" 

$docker logs 8b176116989e
time="2015-11-17T19:37:20Z" level=info msg="Listening for HTTP" addr="0.0.0.0:3376" proto=tcp 
time="2015-11-17T19:37:40Z" level=error msg="Discovery error: Get https://discovery.hub.docker.com/v1/clusters/b54d8665e72939d2c611d8f9e99521b4: dial tcp: lookup discovery.hub.docker.com on 8.8.4.4:53: read udp 172.17.0.2:44241->8.8.4.4:53: i/o timeout"
```

Is it a bug of the generic driver ?

Some others informations :

```
# docker version
 Client:
 Version:      1.9.0
 API version:  1.21
 Go version:   go1.4.2
 Git commit:   76d6bc9
 Built:        Tue Nov  3 17:29:38 UTC 2015
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.9.0
 API version:  1.21
 Go version:   go1.4.2
 Git commit:   76d6bc9
 Built:        Tue Nov  3 17:29:38 UTC 2015
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

# docker info
Containers: 2
Images: 8
Server Version: 1.9.0
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 12
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Logging Driver: json-file
Kernel Version: 3.16.0-4-amd64
Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 1000 MiB
Name: swarm-master
ID: 6SDE:CQRA:NM6W:TY2H:4DPB:O4YO:IGRT:33AA:OKQP:M6UK:EMSR:H4WR
WARNING: No memory limit support
WARNING: No swap limit support
Labels:
 provider=generic
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to use an alternative backend? Consul, etcd or zookeeper can run locally. In fact token based discovery doesn't support the new docker networking features in version 1.9. (See: https://docs.docker.com/swarm/discovery/)

Comment: I tried with a static list with :  ```--swarm-discovery "nodes://192.168.2.[0:10]:2375,localhost:2375"``` 
But I have this error :
```time="2015-11-18T08:49:40Z" level=error msg="Get https://localhost:2375/v1.15/info: dial tcp [::1]:2375: getsockopt: connection refused"```

Comment: Do you have a swarm agent running on each node? Running on port 2375? That would explain the lack of connection. Additionally the documentation states you need consul, etcd or zookeeper in order to support the new networking model. The documentation contains a consul example: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/get-started-overlay/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that it's not possible to use docker machine to create the swarm-master on the same machine. So I created two VM, one with docker-machine (and mh-keystore) and one other for swarm-master.

Creating the mh-keystore on localhost :

```
$docker-machine create -d generic --generic-ip-address localhost mh-keystore
$docker $(docker-machine config mh-keystore) run -d \
    -p "8500:8500" \
    -h "consul" \
    progrium/consul -server -bootstrap
$docker ps
```

Installation of swarm-master to the other machine

```
$ docker-machine create \
-d generic --generic-ip-address 192.168.2.100 \
--swarm --swarm-image="swarm" --swarm-master \
--swarm-discovery="consul://192.168.2.103:8500" \
swarm-master
```

Creation of agent :

```
$ docker-machine create \
-d generic --generic-ip-address 192.168.2.102 \
--swarm \
--swarm-discovery="consul://192.168.2.103:8500" \
swarm-agent-00
```